# how to pass struct from vb to dll?

Tags: dll, vb6

I'm trying to pass a struct from vb to dll im facinf isues on that.

//Datalink layer.cpp

```
 #include"DataLinkLayer.h"
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <windows.h>


  int __stdcall DataLink_TellTale_Encode (struct telltalelib *st_telltale, LPSTR * rtnFramePassedPtr)
 {
  sprintf(*rtnFramePassedPtr,"<%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d>",NORMAL,STREAM,VEHICLEOVERALL,NA,PERCENTAGE,TELLTALEID,COMPIDNA,TELLTALELENGTH,st_telltale.Telltaleid,st_telltale.color,st_telltale.glowLevel,st_telltale.onOff);
 return 0;
}
```

//Datalink Layer.h

```
  #define MAXFRAMELEN 20
  #define MAXPOSSOPTFIELDS 50
  #define RESERVED 0
  #define COMPIDNA 0
  #define NA 1
  #define SPEEDLENGTH 1
  #define RPMLENGTH 1
  #define FUELLENGTH 1
  #define TELLTALELENGTH 3

 struct telltalelib
{
 int Telltaleid; 
 int color;
 int glowLevel;
 int onOff;
};



 int __stdcall DataLink_TellTale_Encode (struct telltalelib *st_telltale, char* rtnFramePassedPtr);

  enum priority{ LOW=1  , NORMAL,   HIGH,   CRITICAL,FATAL };
  enum frameType{ REQUEST=1,    RESPONSE,   ERROR,  STREAM, NOTIFICATION,    STATEINFORMATIONCHANGE,    PERIODIC };
  enum domain{MODULEPOWER=1,MODULESTATEMACHINE,VEHICLEOVERALL,ENGINE,TRANSMISSION,BRAKE,SAFETYSYSTEMS,LOCK,DRIVER,AC,DOOR,TPMS,LIGHTS,WINDOW,   ANTENNA,SEATS,VEHICLEATTITUDE,WIPER,ORVM,DISPLAY,VEHICLECONSTANTS,TELEPHONY,INFOTAINMENT,FOTA };
   enum Parameter{ SPEED=2  ,RPM    ,FUEL,  ODO ,TEMPERATURE,   PRESSURE,   HUMIDITY,BATTERYLEVEL,  ONOFF , GLOWLEVEL,  COLOR,  OPENPOSITION,   RAMPSTYLE,  CMDSHUTDOWN,    CMDREBOOT,  NOTIFICATIONTEXT,   CURRENT,    DRIVEMODE,  GEARLEVEL,  MASS,   VOLUME, DATAPACKET  ,SLIDELEVEL ,RECLINELEVEL,  DRIVERID,   DRIVINGSCORE,   MINLEVELSETTING,    MAXLEVELSETTING,    TIME,   ROLL,   PITCH,  YAW,MODE};
   enum Unit{ RAW=2,    SECONDS,    CM  ,M  ,KM,    MILE,   KMPERHOUR,  MILESPERHOUR,   X100RPM,    X1000RPM,   PERCENTAGE, RGB,    PSI,    BAR,    KPA,    DEGCELCIUS, DEGFARANHEIT    ,FULLYOPENORFULYLCLOSED,    ENUMERATEDCODES ,ENUMERATEDFIELDID, V   ,MA,    A,  DEGREE ,    KG  ,CM3,   CC, PLAINTEXT   ,DB ,EPOCHTIME  ,OKNOTOK };
    enum Component{TYREID=2 ,ACVENTID,DOORID,   WINDOWID,   LIGHTID,    ANTENNAID,  TELLTALEID, ACTUATORID,GENERICDATAFIELDID   ,DATAFORMATID,  WIPERID }   ;
```

VB Code:

```
  Private Type struct_telltalelib
  Telltaleid As Integer
  color As Integer
  glowLevel As Integer
  onOff As Integer
  End Type




  Private Declare Function DataLink_TellTale_Encode Lib "C:\MinGW\bin\DataLinkLayer.dll" (ByRef st_telltale As struct_telltalelib, ByRef rtnFramePassedPtr As String) As Integer



 Dim vb_telltale As struct_telltalelib
 Dim str_data As String * 20
 Dim s2 As String
 Dim stringToBeTrasmitted As String



 Private Sub Check1_Click()
  vb_telltale.Telltaleid = 8
  vb_telltale.color = -1
  vb_telltale.glowLevel = -2
  vb_telltale.onOff = 1
  dummy = DataLink_TellTale_Encode(str(vb_telltale), str_data)
  stringToBeTrasmitted = Trim(Mid(Replace(str_data, Chr(0), " "), 1,    InStr(str_data, Chr(0))))
  Timer1.Enabled = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form_Load()
  UART1.PortOpen = True
  End Sub


 Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
 Timer1.Enabled = False
 UART1.Output = stringToBeTrasmitted
 End Sub
```

I'm getting error message like **only user defined in public object modules can be corrected to or from varient or  passed to late -bound functions**.

Comment: after changing str(vb_telltale) to vb_telltale and str_dat size to 100 getting run time error '53' .and pointing the line  **dummy = DataLink_TellTale_Encode(vb_telltale, str_data)**@DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems:

- The struct should be passed as `vb_telltale` rather than `str(vb_telltale)`.
- The string should be declared as `ByVal`.
- The string buffer is likely too small and will be overrun.

Comment: **(ByRef st_telltale As struct_telltalelib, ByRef rtnFramePassedPtr As String)** the return type of string is pointer so only it have given ad By Ref.

Comment: No, you have to do it ByVal as I said. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the VB Type variable must be declared as `Public` in a BAS module. Also, in C an `int` is equivalent to a VB6 `Long`, not an `Integer`, so you'll likely have size and alignment mismatches. There may be other issues but those stand out.

Comment: @Sri - Everywhere you have `As Integer` in your VB code, change it to `As Long`. Change `Private Type`, to `Public Type`. Change `Dim vb_telltale` to `Public vb_telltale` and place both in a `.bas` module, not a form or class module. Change `str_data` to a variable length string and initialize it to contain (say) 1000 spaces. Pass it `ByVal`, not `ByRef` (BSTRs are already pointers). Try that and let us know what happens.